# Azure AD Group users management through a 3rd party software

Tags: entra-id

My organization is fully on Azure AD. Access to the applications in the organization and roles in the applications are managed by AAD groups.

Is there a 3rd party application or an open source project we can host, that delegates authority of managing users in a particular group to a business admin (usually a team lead) where he or she can select an already existing AAD user and add them to the group?
This can be done through Azure Portal but I am looking for a simplified tool. I did google this and didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Access Panel which is located at https://mygroups.microsoft.com

It can be used by users to request group mambership and group owners to manage group membership.

Read all about self-service group management in Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-self-service-management